# Is the perimeter of an ellipse with integer axes irrational?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, rational-points, irrational-numbers

Let $Q$ be an ellipse with integer-length axes $a$ and $b$:
$$ \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1 \;.$$
The perimeter of $Q$ is given by the [complete elliptic integral of the 2nd kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheSecondKind.html), $E(\;)$:
$4 a E(\epsilon)$ where the eccentricity $\epsilon = \sqrt{1-(b/a)^2}$.
Is the following known?

> **Q**. Is the perimeter of an ellipse with integer-length axes $a$ and $b$ always
>   irrational? If not, for which $a,b$ is it rational?

[image: Ellipse21]

           <sub>$a,b=2,1$. Perimeter is approximately $9.051752335744220113037500073330267105760842885887$.</sub>

---

**Answered** by *paul Monsky* in the comments: The perimeter is transcendental!
Established by Theodor Schneider in 1937.

Comment: If you collapse an ellipse down to a line, then you get a rational perimeter immediately :-)

Comment: You should check out Schneider's article, "Arithmetische Untersuchungen elliptischer Integrale" , Math. Ann. 113 (1937),1-13. It may have what you're looking for, and in fact show that the perimeter is transcendental.

Comment: Springer link to Schneider paper: [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01571618).

Comment: Joseph: As an explicit English language reference to the ellipse problem, Waldschmidt gives Schneider's book:"Transcendental numbers" Annals of Mathematical Studies #16, Princeton University Press.

Comment: @paulMonsky: Thanks, Paul, I think you nailed it!

Comment: From the Schneider paper: "Der Wert eines elliptischen Integrals erster oder zweiter Gattung mit algebraischen Koeffizienten und zwischen algebraischen Grenzen ist transzendent."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Answered** by *paul Monsky* in the comments: The perimeter is transcendental!
Established by Theodor Schneider in 1937:

---

[image: Math.Ann.]

---

[image: Satz I]

---

Roughly (Those with better knowledge of Deutsch, please correct!):

> The value of an elliptic integral of the first or second kind with algebraic
>   coefficients and between algebraic limits is transcendental.

Comment: I understand that Wustholz has the following result. Any period of a meromorphic differential on a Riemann surface, when both are defined over a number field, is 0 or transcendental. (I don't know if he handled incomplete integrals between algebraic limits as well).